# Multiple ternary operator in one line in filter function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
let result = myList.map(obj => {
  return({
    "count": obj.key === data.type || obj.key === 'All' ? obj.count-1 : obj.count,
    "name": obj.name
  })
})
```

Above logic will increment one `obj.key`, and on `obj.key` that's equal to `'All'`, but I have another condition, which is to subtract another key. I'm curious how can I make double ternary operator.

Comment: maybe you could add an example without ternary to show what you want.

Comment: You say that above logic increments something, but there is nothing incremented there. You want a "if-elseif-else" with ternary operator?

Comment: Just declare a variable, build the return value line by line to that variable, and return the variable. There's no reason to integrate everything on a one-liner.

Comment: You can chain multiple conditions using the ternary operator, like: a > b ? "a is bigger" : a < b ? "b is bigger" : "equal"

Comment: (obj.key === data.type || obj.key === 'All') ? obj.count-1 : ((obj.key === data.type || obj.key === 'NewCondition') ? obj.count + 1 : obj.count) do you meen nested conditions?

Comment: @AlexandruPupsa I know this is an opinionated comment but its  bad convention to chain multiple ternary conditions. It is always better to use a switch statement or if..else ladder in such case.

Answer (score 0):

In general, every conditional construction like this:

```
if (condition1) {
  a = 1;
} else if (condition2) {
  a = 2;
} else if (condition3) {
  a = 3;
} else {
  a = null;
}
```

you can write like that:

```
a = condition1 ? 1 : condition2 ? 2 : condition3 ? 3 : null;
```